# Fastest way generate and sum arrays

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I am generating a series of Gaussian arrays given a `x` vector of length `(1400)`, and arrays for the sigma, center, amplitude (amp), all with length `(100)`.  I thought the best way to speed this up would be to use numpy and list comprehension:

```py
g = np.sum([(amp[i]*np.exp(-0.5*(x - (center[i]))**2/(sigma[i])**2)) for i in range(len(center))],axis=0)
```

Each row is a gaussian along a vector `x`, and then I sum the columns into a single array of length `x`.

But this doesn't seem to speed things up at all.  I think there is a faster way to do this while avoiding the `for` loop but I can't quite figure out how.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for `np.random.normal(size=100)` ? Here's the [doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.normal.html#numpy.random.Generator.normal)

Comment: Not quite.  I'm trying to generate from a specific list of mu, sigma, and amplitude, not random ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use vectorized computation instead of comprehension so the loops are all performed at c speed.
In order to do so you have to reshape x to be a column vector. For example you could do `x = x.reshape((1400,1))`.
Then you can operate directly on the arrays, like this:
`v=(amp*np.exp(-0.5*(x - (center))**2/(sigma)**2`
Then you obtain an array of shape (1400,100) which you can sum up to a vector by `np.sum(v, axe=1)`

Answer (score 0):

You should try to vectorize all the operations. IMHO the most efficient to first converts your input data to numpy arrays (if they were plain Python lists) and then let numpy process the computations:

```
np_amp = np.array(amp)
np_center = np.array(center)
np_sigma = np.array(sigma)

g = np.sum((np_amp*np.exp(-0.5*(x - (np_center))**2/(np_sigma)**2)),axis=0)
```